# PowerShell run string as a command and add it to history

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-terminal

I really like the new Windows Terminal and it allows users to define custom commands for New Tab action. The problem is - when you run this command you can't repeat it. For example, I have a command to connect to a remote machine over SSH. When connection drops I can't just press arrow up to find the last command and run it again. My command is defined like this:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -Command "vt-vm"
```

It will call my function `vt-vm` but will not add it to the history.

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: the history is - i think - the stuff you enter at the command line in a console. that `vt-vm` was not entered at the command line ... it was fed to the command interpreter directly.

Comment: @LPChip question is - how to add the command that I am running to history?

Comment: Please edit your question and add it in there.

Comment: How is this [-Command "vt-vm"] a function? Unless you have a profile that loads the module or script that hosts the function, at startup, even the function should not run at all. Also, the is not a proper naming convention for PowerShell cmdlet/function. Meaning not using verb-noun construct, unless that is an alias of course.

Comment: vt-vm is a function I defined so I can use it as a short alias for the command. Not sure how this is relevant to my question, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that PSReadLine will only update your History with Commands entered at the Command Line. However, you can work directly with the History file so you can do this

`powershell.exe -noexit -Command "vt-vm ; Add-Content -Value 'vt-vm' -Path (Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath"`

You'll now be able to Up arrow to re-run your function.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0):

As for ...

> ***'how to add the command that I am running to history?'***

... you should not have to do this manually for any reason.

Something else is going on, with your system, as I just tested this on my system and it gets added to history for the session as expected.

From Windows Run GUI or cmd.exe option and typing ...

***powershell.exe -noexit -Command ' Start-ConsoleCommand -ConsoleCommand ping localhost'***

```
# Results in the current consolehost window
 Start-ConsoleCommand -ConsoleCommand ping localhost
 Get-History

  Id CommandLine
  -- -----------
   1 ' Start-ConsoleCommand -ConsoleCommand ping localhost'


 (Get-History).Count
2
 Get-History

  Id CommandLine
  -- -----------
   1 ' Start-ConsoleCommand -ConsoleCommand ping localhost'
   2 Get-History
   3 (Get-History).Count
```

The same thing happens if I use a normal executable.